# PHP MySQL Delete Rows older than 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry for this post that has many answers, but I'm spinning my wheels and am out of ideas. Really simple: delete all records older than 1 minute:

```
function deleteExpiredKeys ($link) {

    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $time = $time - (60);
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);

    $sql = 'DELETE from Session_Keys
            WHERE updated_at < ' . $date;

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (!$result) return false;

    return true;
}
```

'updated_at' is a `datetime` field.

This doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't delete anything either. I've tried many different things, most of them more elegant than what I am posting here, but nothing works. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: You need to quote the date.

Comment: Also why are you forcing a string format on the date and then feeding it through `strtotime()`? `$time=time()-60;`

Comment: @Sammitch - thank you. The quotes were the problem. My convoluted $time variable is just a result of many different attempts, each of which was probably dumber than the previous. I'll clean that up now that I have it working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will silently convert properly formatted strings to dates when comparing against a date/datetime. Your code would send the date not as a string, but as a sequence of characters (strings need to be delimited by quotes).

Try this:

```
function deleteExpiredKeys ($link) {

$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('1 minute ago'));

$sql = 'DELETE from Session_Keys
        WHERE updated_at < ?';

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $date);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

if (!$result) return false;

return true;

}
```

It uses preprared statement, which are a best practice.

Comment: I won't ever argue against using prepared statements; it's indeed something people should get used to doing. - However, with that said, I have to also say that in this particular instance it's sort of unnecessary. The `$date` value is in a known, statically defined format that won't ever present an injection threat.

Comment: I agree that when all quantities are known or computed, there is little to gain from using prepared statements (unless you are doing excessive looping with SQL statements that only differ in values). However, it is a good practice to use them consistently, until they become a performance issue. It'll help prevent moments where you blindly copy a section of functionality, only this time you allow user input (I'm certain we've all done that).

Comment: Thanks, @T0xicCode. Your $date variable is much cleaner than what I posted here, and it works for me. I use prepared statements whenever I have a variable that comes from an outside parameter. In this case I'm going to stick with the simpler method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the time in PHP. MySQL is capable of doing the time calculations by itself.

```
DELETE from Session_Keys
WHERE updated_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

Comment: Thanks, @Atli. I had tried this in one of my earlier attempts, but for some reason it won't work for me. No idea why it is failing...